# Understanding Java Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Please look at the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[10];
    Arrays.setAll(array, operand -> random.nextInt(10));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    swap(array, 0, 9);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i]; // pass by value ??
    array[i] = array[j]; // the value of temp doesn't change, why?
    array[j] = temp; // temp == array[i]
}
```

What exactly happens in the method `swap`?

I need a full explanation and a low level.

**EDIT :**

OK, let me show you another example :

```
public class StringHolder {

    private String value;

    public StringHolder(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getValue();
    }

}
```

main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringHolder[] holders = new StringHolder[]{new StringHolder("string 1")};
    StringHolder tmp = holders[0];
    holders[0].setValue("string 2");
    System.out.println(tmp);
    System.out.println(holders[0]);
}
```

output :

```
string 2
string 2
```

According to @chokdee's answer, `tmp` is a new variable and have it's own piece of memory...

but when we apply changes to the original variable (`holder[0]`), it also affects `tmp`.

another example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringHolder[] holders = new StringHolder[]{new StringHolder("string 1")};
    StringHolder tmp = holders[0];
    holders[0] = new StringHolder("string 2");
    System.out.println(tmp);
    System.out.println(holders[0]);
}
```

output :

```
string 1
string 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feels a lot like a homework question...

Comment: Are you sure? I remember an almost identical question as homework back in my university days :)

Comment: I need a full explanation and a *low level*. Sure, its not homework?

Comment: if you could tell what your inference is from the snippet, and what you do not understand, people would be glad to help you. There is nothing big in the snippet you see..

Comment: The different is in the first example you're using primitive values in the second one you're using objects.
Please see http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: you're welcome, please mark my answer as the correct one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your edit question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringHolder[] holders = new StringHolder[]{new StringHolder("string 1")};
    StringHolder tmp = holders[0];
    holders[0].setValue("string 2");
    System.out.println(tmp); // string 2
    System.out.println(holders[0]); // string 2
}
```

Because both are holding a reference to the same object.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringHolder[] holders = new StringHolder[]{new StringHolder("string 1")};
    StringHolder tmp = holders[0];
    holders[0] = new StringHolder("string 2");
    System.out.println(tmp); // string 1
    System.out.println(holders[0]); // string 2
}
```

In this case the reference is hold by tmp. After you assign a new `StringHolder` object to `holders[0]` the reference in tmp is turned to the actual object.
Normally, if you did not have a `tmp` the Garbage Collector would remove the object.
In the end you have *two* different `StringHolder` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Ok trying to explain on a low level.

```
int temp = array[i]; // storing the value in a new variable

array[i] = array[j]; // the value of temp wan't changes because this is a NEW variable and have it's own piece of memory (It's no a reference or pointer like in C)

array[j] = temp; // here the value inside the array is assigned with saved value in temp
```

Comment: That's not low level.

Comment: @MuratK. That depends on what the OP means by low level. Judging by the understanding level of the OP, I am sure this is low enough :)

Answer (score 0):

The item in the array at position i is swapped with the item at position j. So the item formerly known as array[i] will be found at array[j] after the method is returned. And the item formerly known as array[j] will be found at array[i] after the method returned.

Also the temp variable is used as swap space.

Answer (score 0):

```
int temp = array[i]; // pass by value ??
```

copies the element at position `i` to `temp`.

```
array[i] = array[j]; // the value of temp doesn't change, why?
```

copies the value at position `j` to position `i`. `temp` doesn't change since it's a variable not accessed in this statement. `temp` is a **copy** and not a alias for `array[i]`.

```
array[j] = temp; // temp == array[i]
```

copies the value that *was* at position `i` before the assignment in the previous line to position `j`. `temp == array[i]` if and only if `array[i] == array[j]` at the beginning of the method.